# Minor and major tick marks both in and out on all subplot x-axes

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, xticks

I am having a subplot series where I want to display both minor and major tick marks on all x-axis in inner and outer directions for all of them. I tried something like :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,figsize=(10,6), sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1,1]})
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
ax[0].tick_params(top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="in")
```

But some ticks on the top axix of the top plot are inwards some others are outward

Comment: You could try `for ax_in ax:  ax_i.tick_params(axis='x', top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="inout")`.  So, `axis='x'` to avoid `y` also being changed. And `direction='inout'`.  Note that the middle subplot will hide the outside ticks of the upper subplot; with `ax[1].set_facecolor('none')` the middle plot could have a transparent background.

Comment: @JohanC this kinda works for the major ticks, but not for the minor ones. Perhaps relevant: I am on a log scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from a loop over the axis, using the `tick_params()` call you already have:

```py
for ax in axs:
    ax.tick_params(top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="in")
```

> I want to display both minor and major tick marks

Use the `which` parameter set to `"both"`, which is by default "major".

```py
ax.tick_params(which="both", top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="in")
```

> on all x-axis

Use the `axis` parameter set to `"x"`, which is by default "both".

```py
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="in")
```

> in inner and outer directions for all of them

Set the `direction` parameter to `inout` instead of `in`.

```py
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="inout")
```

---

Displaying the grid, here is the result

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,figsize=(10,6), sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1,1]})
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

for ax in axs:
    ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", top=True, labeltop=False, bottom=True, labelbottom=False, direction="inout")
```

[image]

It's hard to see the ticks on the figure, you might want to play with the `length` parameter of the `tick_params()` function. Example:

[image]

Reference: [Axes.tick_params doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)